# Binding Context and Update form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to update my User object only when **Submit** button is pressed and not every time Entry text changed (While the value didn't change in Database it changed in the entry when we select the user again (See Images EDIT : I can't post image, i will just put the link))

My problem is that when I change data in entry it automatically change it in the `ViewModel` (and that's normal ! because Entry binding mode is set to `TwoWay`) yet I want to update the data only when I press the submit button

I changed all the value of the User Test but I didn't press submit
(1234 > 12 / Test > TestModify / User > Manager)
Image display the value before I changed them :

[image]

I clicked on the element before Test in the list (its Role = Administrator)

[image]

Then i clicked again on 1234 (The value changed because of the `Mode=TwoWay` of the `Entry`)

[image]

```
     private ObservableCollection<User> users;
        public ObservableCollection<User> Users
        {
            get { return users; }
            set
            {
                if (users != value)
                {

                    users = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => Users);
                }
            }
        }

        private User selectedUser;
        public User SelectedUser
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedUser;
            }
            set
            {
                if(selectedUser != value){

                selectedUser = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedUser);
                }
            }
        }
```

OnItemSelected in my Listview I fill my form entry using Binding.

```
<StackLayout Spacing="20">
                        <Entry Placeholder="{localization:Localization UserCode}" Text="{Binding SelectedUser.UserCode, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        <Entry Placeholder="{localization:Localization UserName}" Text="{Binding SelectedUser.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

```
  <Button
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    BackgroundColor="#8bc34a"
                                    Command="{Binding Submit}"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                    Text="{localization:Localization Submit}"
                                    TextColor="White"
                                    WidthRequest="150" />
```

My command :

```
   public async void SubmitAsync()
        {
            if (isEdit)
            {
                //TODO : Add Task.Run for Async function
                App.DatabaseManager.Update(selectedUser);
                int index = users.IndexOf(users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == selectedUser.Id));
                Users[index] = SelectedUser;
            }
            else
            {
                App.DatabaseManager.Insert(selectedUser);
                users.Add(selectedUser);
            }
            IsVisible = false;
        }
```

PS : If I set `OneWay` mode for Entry I can't get the new value when Submit button is pressed (any idea how i could do it ? My `ViewModel` doesn't have access to the View)

I tried to call `RaiseOnPropertyChanged()` in the submit command.

I tried to call `RaiseOnPropertyChanged()` in the New command (that set my `SelectedUser` to `new User()`)

I think that I need to call `RaiseOnPropertyChanged()` that is a function like `OnPropertyChanged()` only when I press the Submit Button (somehow)

Please could you excuse my english it's not my mother tongue

Comment: create a copy of your user before you edit - if the user does not save, then restore the original copy

Comment: Yeaht that's something I didn't think about... Thank you, I'm gonna try it.

Comment: Well, It doesn't work, even the saved User is modified, I don't even know how that happen both EditedUser and SelectedUser are modified by the Entry.
Anyway thank you for your tips

Comment: are you actually creating a copy, or are you just creating another variable that points to the same instance of the class?

Comment: Seem like I pointed to the same instance...
Now it work :  I created a controller in my User class where I pass a User object yet i don't think that's really effective. Atleast I don't need a copy of my User now